# Fragment doesn't initialize when Activity in background

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragments in ViewPager doesn't initialize when parent activity in background.

My Application's Tree:

```
MainActivity
 >FragmentViewPager
   >Fragment1
    >FragmentViewPager
      >FragmentA, B, C
   >Fragment2
SplashActivity
```

In my case, **MainActivity** start with **SplashActivity**. (SplashActivity started from MainActivity's onCreate)

**Fragment 1 and 2** has been initialized, But **Fragment A, B and C** dosen't initializing. they only going to initialize when **MainActivity** on the foreground.

Comment: **On a side note.** If you start a `SplashActivity` with `startActivityForResult`, `The onActivityCreated Solve` is not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, you can initiate your `FragmentA,B,C` from methods `@Override onActivityCreated(...)` In `Fragment1`.

Hope this help!

Comment: it's works! i'm just put `FragmentViewPager` initiate code at `onActivityCreated` in `Fragment1`. that's what i want. really helpful. thanks!